# User Defined Function in mysql for splitting Column in Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, split, user-defined-functions

I have a primary column let's say A with values 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.

And, I have target column let's say T with values like 111111111, AAAAAA, 111, 222222. This is in the form of string.

So the table will be something like:

```
1 | 111111111

2 | AAAAAA
```

and so on...

The length of each value in "target" column will be in multiple of 3 but the total length can vary i.e. 6,9,15,93 etc.

I want the output to be split by 3 letters in rows i.e.

1 | 111111111

2 | AAAAAA

should be split as:

```
1 | 111 | 1
1 | 111 | 2
1 | 111 | 3
2 | AAA | 1
2 | AAA | 2
```

The third column here is basically an identifier for each split number.

I understand there is no direct function in mySQl to do this and will need a UDF.

Comment: @phoenix05 . . . Your question is quite confusing.  You have tagged it MySQL, but your code is SQL Server.  Please check the database you are using and fix the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for replying and Apologies for the confusion. I have started using MySQL very recently and wasn't aware the code I found was of SQL Server. I don't have the exact syntax but I hope you understand the question I am trying to ask based on the algorithm (or my explanation). If you want me to reiterate the question or there is any part you don't get then let me know.

Comment: . . You should remove the code and focus on the question you want answered.

Comment: Done, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Careful with the term user defined function - 'For the UDF mechanism to work, functions must be written in C++ and your operating system must support dynamic loading. ' is this what you really mean or do you mean a stored function (which cannot anyway return many rows)